# how to make comment div active on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

i have 4 divs having 4 images.when a user hover over an image the comment div will appear with user comment.my problem is that i want to make that first image active and comment div active on page load.i have given active class to that div but i want to do it dynamicaly .how can i do it.

Here is my code:

```css
.media-user-items {
  padding: 240px 0 0px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.media-user-items .user-item {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease opacity;
  -o-transition: 0.3s ease opacity;
  transition: 0.3s ease opacity
}
.media-user-items .user-item.active {
  opacity: 1
}
.media-user-items .user-item.active .user-comment {
  display: block;
}
.media-user-items .user-comment {
  display: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}
body:not(.touch) .media-user-items .user-comment-content {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  max-width: 820px;
}
.user-item:hover .user-comment {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-fluid media-user-items">
  <div class="span6 user-item">
    <div class="user-comment">
      <div class="user-comment-content">The slice view for #TataValueHomes is awesome. Beautifully crafted engineering product. Great pitch for #SoftwareEngineers</div>
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img_circle" />
    <div class="username">XYZ</div>
    <div class="userid user-item">@xyz</div>
  </div>
  <div class="span6 user-item">
    <div class="user-comment">
      <div class="user-comment-content">Drool worthy ur site truly is. Data sciences blew my mind. Showing ph no. to moving out while searching is masterclass!!</div>
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img_circle" />
    <div class="username">XYZ</div>
    <div class="userid">@xyz</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i do it with css or do i need jquery??

Comment: On which hover you need to show the comment div.

Comment: i want to show it on every image.every image has its own comment.

Comment: @stanze: i have added active class manualy but i want to add it dynamicaly.on page load first image and comment box will remain active and then when we hover the next image it became active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vanilla javascript solution,

1. Set the first item as active
2. Assign a mouseover event listener to each item

   1. On mouseover of each item set the current active to inactive
   2. Set hovered item to active

assign a mouseover event listener to each item, on mouseover remove the

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/6yeanpzu/3/))

```
(function () {
    "use strict"
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('user-item'), item;
    items[0].className += ' active';
    for (var i = 0; item = items[i]; i++) {
        item.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
            var activeItems = document.getElementsByClassName('active'), active;
            for(var x = 0; active = activeItems[x]; i++) {
                active.className = active.className.replace(' active', '');
            }
            this.className += ' active';
        }, false);
    }
})();
```

Comment: its working but when we goes to 4th or last image and again come back to first it shows the last one always active???

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.media-user-items').on('hover', '.img_circle', function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).siblings('.user-comment').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer bro...i want just like this,please checkwhat drive us section at bottom of page.

link:https://housing.com/in

Comment: `when a user hover over an image the comment div will appear with user comment` in question

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) function.

```
$('.user-item').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active')
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active')
    }
)
```

Comment: thanks buddy its working like a charm.just one problem that the first one should remain active on page load. just like this link please check "what drive us" section.
https://housing.com/in